# Stripes ignores submit button event

Tags: java, stripes

I am using Stripes framework and I have a problem I just cannot solve.

I have a page in the folder "creatures" called "add.jsp" which adds a creature (some entity in my model) into the DB. I use this form in that page:

add.jsp

```
<s:layout-render name="/layout.jsp" title="Creatures">
<s:layout-component name="menu">
    <ul class="navcontainer" id="main-navigation">
        <li><s:link href="/regions.jsp">Region</s:link></li>
        <li class="current"><s:link href="/creatures/show.jsp">Creatures</s:link></li>
        <li><s:link href="/types.jsp">Creature types</s:link></li>
        <li><s:link href="/weapons.jsp">Weapons</s:link></li>
    </ul>
</s:layout-component>
<s:layout-component name="main_content">
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content">
            <img src="../images/banner.png" alt="Banner" id="banner"/>
            <h1>Create a new creature</h1>
            <s:link href="/creatures/show.jsp">Back</s:link>
            <s:form beanclass="cz.muni.fi.pa165.creatures.web.CreaturesActionBean">
                <%@include file="/forms/createCreature.jsp"%>
                <s:submit name="create" value="Create"/>
            </s:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</s:layout-component>
```

so that is pretty it, i also include form itself and I have a submit button with name="create" which should map on the method "create" in the action bean right?

Ok so I have that class which looks like this:

```
@UrlBinding("/creatures/{$event}")
public class CreaturesActionBean implements ActionBean {

final static Logger logger = 
    Logger.getLogger(CreaturesActionBean.class.getName());

private ActionBeanContext context;

@SpringBean
protected CreatureService creatureService;

@ValidateNestedProperties(value = {
    @Validate(on = {"create"}, field = "name", required = true, maxlength=256),
    @Validate(converter=LongTypeConverter.class , on = {"create"}, 
        field = "weight", required = false, minvalue=1, maxvalue=1000),
    @Validate(converter=LongTypeConverter.class , on = {"create"}, 
        field = "height", required = false, minvalue=1, maxvalue=1000)
})
private CreatureDTO creatureDTO;

public void setCreatureDTO(CreatureDTO creatureDTO) {
    this.creatureDTO = creatureDTO;
}

public CreatureDTO getCreatureDTO() {
    return this.creatureDTO;
}

public Resolution create() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "add() creature={}", creatureDTO);
    creatureService.create(creatureDTO);
    return new RedirectResolution(this.getClass(), "all");
}

@DefaultHandler
public Resolution all() {
    logger.log(Level.INFO, "getting all creatures");
    return new ForwardResolution("/creatures/show.jsp");
}
```

So it means that when there is a submit with name "create", in that action bean the create method is executed and the creatureDTO is saved and so on.

**BUT**

That "create" method in the action bean is not executed at all and **i am redirected to the page called**

```
http://localhost:8080/pa165/creatures/
```

Application context is pa165 and after redirecting to that page after I click submit button, I see the listing of all files in that directory (add.jsp and so in, the all files in the creature dir) and that **method is not executed at all**.

I want to be redirected to the page creatures/show.jsp which I handle by line

```
return new RedirectResolution(this.getClass(), "all");
```

which means that I will be redirected throught all method there

Why it does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Do you output validation results anywhere? (<stripes:errors> tag) The 'create' method not being executed at all could suggest form submissions do not pass validation. Maybe a field name not matching or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the URL binding should not be the same as the folder structure. Just change the binding for something like `@UrlBinding("/mycreatures/{$event}")`. I had the same problem and this worked like a charm. See [this link](http://www.mail-archive.com/stripes-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05413.html) for more info.